# Angular.js / Javascript: checking if an object is found in any of the elements of an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that is structured like this:

```
$scope.roomlist = [
    {"roomid":"1", "tablecount":"10", "chaircount":"20", "whiteboards":"2"}, 
    {"roomid":"2", "tablecount":"15", "chaircount":"30", "whiteboards":"2"}, 
    {"roomid":"3", "tablecount":"10", "chaircount":"20"}];
```

The array values are dynamic and the array is generated by joining some tables.  Whiteboards is one of the elements that may exist in all the rooms returned in the `roomlist`, may exist in some of the rooms as shown above or none of the rooms at all.

All I need to do is test to see if there is at least one room in the list which has the whiteboard object.

I have tried the `indexOf` test but it returns -1.

The code I executed, was

```
var myrooms = $scope.roomlist; 
var results = myrooms.indexOf("whiteboards");
```

And then

```
console.log(results);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `roomlist` is an array of dictionaries, but you're indexing a string, the result is always going to be `-1`, meaning not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterated room by room, and then check for existence.

```
function searchRoomsFor(objectName, roomList) {
  var found = false;
  for (var roomIndex in roomList) {
    var room = roomList[roomIndex];
    if (objectName in room) {
      found = true;
    }
  }
  return found;
}

// Check for an object
console.log(searchRoomsFor('whiteboards', $scope.roomlist));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I replaced false and true with 0 and 1 to put conditional logic in my presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check there is a room with at least one whitboard, then you can simply use `Array.prototype.some`:

```js
var roomlist = [
    {"roomid":"1", "tablecount":"10", "chaircount":"20", "whiteboards":"2"}, 
    {"roomid":"2", "tablecount":"15", "chaircount":"30", "whiteboards":"2"}, 
    {"roomid":"3", "tablecount":"10", "chaircount":"20"}
];

var anyRoomWithWhiteBoard = roomlist.some(room => room.whiteboards && parseInt(room.whiteboards) > 0);

console.log(anyRoomWithWhiteBoard);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to find the first index of a key in an array of objects you need to perform a loop.

```
var index = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.roomlist.length; i++) {
    // check if the whiteboards property is defined
    if (typeof roomlist[i].whiteboards !== 'undefined') {
        var index = i;
        break; // we've found one, stop looping
    }
}
console.log(index);
```

There is new, and poorly support, [`array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method which can simplify the previous loop to the following. It calls a function for each item and returns the index of the first item where the function returns `true`.

```
var indexOfWhiteboardRoom = $scope.roomlist.findIndex(function(room, index, arr) {
    return typeof room.whiteboard !== 'undefined';
});
```

If you want to find the first room with a whiteboard you can use with [`array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Which calls a function for each item in the array and returns the first item where the function returns `true`.

```
var whiteboardRoom = $scope.roomlist.find(function(room, index, arr) {
    return typeof room.whiteboard !== 'undefined';
});
```

If you're trying to find all the objects that have a `whiteboard` property defined, you can use [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Which calls a function for each item in the array and returns only the items where the result of the function is `true`.

```
var whiteboardRooms = $scope.roomlist.filter(function(room, index, arr) {
    return typeof room.whiteboard !== 'undefined';
});
```

If you just want to know if a `whiteboard` exists.

```
var whiteboardExists = $scope.roomlist.some(function(room, index, arr) {
    return typeof room.whiteboard !== 'undefined';
});
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.some` checks if whiteboards exist. so maybe better to change the statement about it (If you want to find the first room with a whiteboard...).

Comment: I already did. I was thinking of `array.find()` when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use lodash library to find out if the whilteboard exist or not

```
$scope.roomlist = [{
    "roomid": "1",
    "tablecount": "10",
    "chaircount": "20",
    "whiteboards": "2"
   }, {
   "roomid": "2",
   "tablecount": "15",
   "chaircount": "30",
   "whiteboards": "2"
   }, {
   "roomid": "3",
   "tablecount": "10",
   "chaircount": "20"
}];

var myrooms = $scope.roomlist;
w = _.find(myrooms, function(r) {
    return r.whiteboards
});
if (w) {
    alert("there is a whiteboard");
} else {
    alert("there is no white board")
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phpforyou/jv5hzsvh/

Comment: this works too.  But i just decided to go with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Similar As Your Question

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var check = [3, 4];

var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
if (arr.indexOf(check[i]) > -1) {
    found = true;
    break;
}
}
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont able to get `indexOf('whiteboards')` in `$scope.roomlist` because whiteboards is not direct element of the array roomlist. So you have to iterate it. And using AngularJS angular.forEach() is the best way to do.

```
var hasWhiteboards;
angular.forEach($scope.roomlist, function (list) {
  if (list.whiteboards) {
    hasWhiteboards = true;
  }
});
```